# How to display an error only with the invalid email in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I want to display an error if the user enters an invalid email.
But fails.
This is my code:
Every time I try to add another check on the email element I get an error
I have a feeling that something needs to be added to the config ts file
But I do not know what

```
<form class="card" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="card-content">
    <span class="card-title">Welcome</span>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input formControlName="email" id="email" type="email" />

      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <span class="helper-text red-text" *ngIf="form.get('email')?.invalid">
        error
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input formControlName="password" id="password" type="password" />
      <label for="password">password:</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-action">
    <button
      type="submit"
      class="modal-action btn waves-effect"
      [disabled]="form.invalid"
    >
      login
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;


  ngOnInit() {`enter code here`
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6),
      ]),
    });
  }

  

  onSubmit() {}
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: "Every time I try to add another check on the email element I get an error". Please add in the error mentioned to improve the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We should use below code for email formcontrol error check in HTML

> *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors?.required || form.controls['email'].errors?.email"

Comment: The truth is I did not understand you. I tried to copy what you wrote and it does not work

Comment: Please check stackblitz link. Hope, it will solve your problem
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ubbuhm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: When I try to copy your code I get the following errors:
https://postimg.cc/bGzr71fC
https://postimg.cc/D8Lzmx2p

Comment: As you can see in 2nd screenshot, `Object is possibly null`
We can use `optional chanining` ie, first check object exist or not...if it exist then try to access its properties

eg <span *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors?.required">
`?` is used for optional chaining


Reference:[Opional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties)